# webpack + Karma configuration through Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I configure webpack + karma + angular 2 and have some **Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token import** with it. I do not understand why it occurs.When I run **$karma start** it through me this error.Plaese help me.

**error**

```
START:

webpack: bundle is now VALID.
webpack: bundle is now INVALID.

webpack: bundle is now VALID.
01 10 2016 21:19:23.983:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
01 10 2016 21:19:23.986:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
01 10 2016 21:19:23.992:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
01 10 2016 21:19:26.183:INFO [Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#lvvCZVUPfIeWdbpWAAAA with id 1306097
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/debug/by.js:8:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72359
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
  at webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/debug/by.js:8:0 <- config/spec-bundle.js:72359

Finished in 0.483 secs / 0 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 0 tests completed
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js')({env: 'test'});

  var configuration = {

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
basePath: '',

/*
 * Frameworks to use
 *
 * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
 */
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// list of files to exclude
exclude: [ ],

/*
 * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
 *
 * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.js
 */
files: [

  { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.js', watched: false }

],

/*
 * preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
 * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
 */
preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

// Webpack Config at ./webpack.test.js
webpack: testWebpackConfig,

coverageReporter: {
  type: 'in-memory'
},

remapCoverageReporter: {
  'text-summary': null,
  json: './coverage/coverage.json',
  html: './coverage/html'
},



// Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
webpackMiddleware: { stats: 'errors-only'},

/*
 * test results reporter to use
 *
 * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
 * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
 */
reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage', 'remap-coverage' ],

// web server port
port: 9876,

// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,

/*
 * level of logging
 * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
 */
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,

/*
 * start these browsers
 * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
 */
browsers: [
  'Chrome'
],

customLaunchers: {
  ChromeTravisCi: {
    base: 'Chrome',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
},

plugin:[
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-mocha-reporter',
  'karma-remap-coverage',
  'karma-sourcemap-loader',

],

/*
 * Continuous Integration mode
 * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
 */
singleRun: true


};

  if (process.env.TRAVIS){
    configuration.browsers = [
      'ChromeTravisCi',
      'Chrome'
    ];
  }

  config.set(configuration);


 };
```

**webpack.test.js**

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/**
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

/**
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = function(options) {
  return {

    /**
     * Source map for Karma from the help of karma-sourcemap-loader &  karma-webpack
     *
     * Do not change, leave as is or it wont work.
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack#source-maps
     */
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    /**
     * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    resolve: {

      /**
       * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
       */
      extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],

      /**
       * Make sure root is src
       */
      root: helpers.root('src'),

    },

    /**
     * Options affecting the normal modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
     */
    module: {

      /**
       * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
       */
      preLoaders: [

        /**
         * Tslint loader support for *.ts files
         *
         * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'tslint-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('node_modules')]
        },

        /**
         * Source map loader support for *.js files
         * Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'source-map-loader',
          exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular')
        ]}

      ],

      /**
       * An array of automatically applied loaders.
       *
       * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
       * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
       */
      loaders: [

        /**
         * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
         *
         * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          query: {
            // use inline sourcemaps for "karma-remap-coverage" reporter
            sourceMap: false,
            inlineSourceMap: true,
            compilerOptions: {

              // Remove TypeScript helpers to be injected
              // below by DefinePlugin
              removeComments: true

            }
          },
          exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
        },

        /**
         * Json loader support for *.json files.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
         */
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] },

        /**
         * Raw loader support for *.css files
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'], exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] },

        /**
         * Raw loader support for *.html
         * Returns file content as string
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
         */
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader', exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')] }

      ],

      /**
       * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
       */
      postLoaders: [

        /**
         * Instruments JS files with Istanbul for subsequent code coverage reporting.
         * Instrument only testing sources.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/deepsweet/istanbul-instrumenter-loader
         */
        {
          test: /\.(js|ts)$/, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
          include: helpers.root('src'),
          exclude: [
            /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
            /node_modules/
          ]
        }

      ]
    },

    /**
     * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     */
    plugins: [

      /**
       * Plugin: DefinePlugin
       * Description: Define free variables.
       * Useful for having development builds with debug logging or adding global constants.
       *
       * Environment helpers
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
       */
      // NOTE: when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
        'HMR': false,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV),
          'HMR': false,
        }
      }),


    ],

    /**
     * Static analysis linter for TypeScript advanced options configuration
     * Description: An extensible linter for the TypeScript language.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
     */
    tslint: {
      emitErrors: false,
      failOnHint: false,
      resourcePath: 'src'
    },

    /**
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: 'window',
      process: false,
      crypto: 'empty',
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  };
}
```

**spec-bundle.js**

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js/es6');
require('core-js/es7/reflect');

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
require('ts-helpers');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/proxy'); // since zone.js 0.6.15
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch'); // put here since zone.js 0.6.14
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');

// RxJS
require('rxjs/Rx');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  browser.BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  browser.platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);

/*
 * Ok, this is kinda crazy. We can use the context method on
 * require that webpack created in order to tell webpack
 * what files we actually want to require or import.
 * Below, context will be a function/object with file names as keys.
 * Using that regex we are saying look in ../src then find
 * any file that ends with spec.ts and get its path. By passing in true
 * we say do this recursively
 */
var testContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

/*
 * get all the files, for each file, call the context function
 * that will require the file and load it up here. Context will
 * loop and require those spec files here
 */
function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

// requires and returns all modules that match
var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I was having a similar issue. I resolved it by **upgrading to webpack: "2.1.0-beta.21".**

I had previously been on 1.13 and I was getting

> Chrome 52.0.2743 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR   Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token import   at webpack:///~/@angular/test_bed

Comment: I am also using "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.21" and getting this problem